# Sorting function in a class

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a class Client :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
class Client
{
    private:
    vector<Liked*>like;
    public:
    Client();
    ~Client();
    sort_id();
};
```

where like is a vector connection between class Client and Liked.
I created adding function:

```
void Client::addLiked(int id, string title)
{
            Liked* newLiked= new Liked(id, title, year, minute, genre);
            like.push_back(newLiked);
            return ;
}
```

which is responsible for adding movie to the list. I would like to have sorting function, which will sort id in ascending order while printing the whole list :

```
void Client::print_Liked()
{
    int n = like.size();
    if(n == 0)
    {
        cout<<"Is empty"<<endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sort_id();
        like[i]->print_Liked();
    }
}
```

I have tried with a bubble sort but I got errors :

```
void Client::sort_id()
{
    int n = like.size();
    bool swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int temp;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for(int i = 0;i < n - j;++i)
        {
            if(like[i]->getID() > like[i+1]->getID())
            {
                temp = like[i]->getID();
                like[i]->getID() = like[i+1]->getID();
                array[i+1]->getID() = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I got errors_ is not useful. Please edit your question to include the errors.

Comment: Why use pointers? Why not use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)? Why sort *inside* the loop?

Comment: I would surmise `like[i]->getID() = like[i+1]->getID();` is harfing up a nice "not an lvalue" error, but without knowing what a `Liked` looks like, that's sheer guessing, which makes for lousy answers.

Comment: Also, what is `array` in the second to last non-bracket line of `sort_id`? Seems a typo.

Comment: Array is what is left after my earlier attempts. I got expression in not assignable error. I tried with std::sort but I don’t know how to use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to sort your vector is by using the standard [`std::sort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) together with a suitable [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for the comparisons.

Something like this:

```
void Client::sort_id()
{
    std::sort(begin(like), end(like), [](Liked const* a, Liked const* b)
    {
        return a->getID() > b->getID();
    });
}
```